# mongoose save() operation is generating repeated _id

Tags: node.js, mongodb, mongoose, mongoose-schema

I have the following mongoose schema:

```
var mongoose = require('mongoose');

module.exports = mongoose.model('lf', {
    _set : {type:Number},
    a : {type:String},
    b : {type:String},
    c : {type:Number},
    created_at  : {type: Date, default: Date.now},
    updated_at  : {type: Date, default: Date.now}
},'flr');
```

In my code I query the some collections and produce a stitched json object which contains the above schema.

although when I am making the save() operation on the mongoose I keep getting:

```
Collection1.findOne({tfC: tfC}).lean().then(FP=> {
    if ( FP!== null && FP!== undefined ){
        new linkedFixed(FP).save(function(err, result){
            console.log(err);
            process.exit();
        });
    }
}).catch(error => {
    console.error(error);
});
```

I am getting error:

```
{ MongoError: E11000 duplicate key error collection: Da.flr index: _id_ dup key: { : ObjectId('5a0c8b3f10dfe503505fcaec') }  at Function.MongoError.create
```

I do not define this _id in my schema so Why is mongoose generating duplicate entries on this index?

I was able to understand that the json object from the find already contains an _id. I then remove this and I get the error:

```
MongooseError: document must have an _id before saving
```

How can I save a json object to a collection without passing _id? SHould'nt _id be assigned randomly and unique by mongoose?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem comes from the lean(). When using lean _id is returning from the mongoose query.

If removing lean() _id is not part of the document content and hence not overriden.

Answer (score 0):

Use $project in your findOne method to avoid _id (Object ID) returning from query as below: 
    `Collection1.findOne({tfC: tfC},{_id:0})`

For more details refer to [MongoDB Aggregation $project](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/project/)

Answer (score 0):

As @JoaoFilipeClementeMartins said, problem is with lean you are getting _id too, and you are passing _id to the new object and trying to save it. Another possible solution is to remove _id before set it into the new object.

```
delete FP._id;
new linkedFixed(FP).save(function(err, result){
```